# Node sass watch builds changed file directly instead of entry point file

Tags: css, sass, command-line-interface, node-sass

I'm trying to use a simple script with `node-sass v4.8.3` which builds my SASS code:

```
./node_modules/node-sass/bin/node-sass ./sass/import.scss source/css/style.css --watch
```

If I use it without the `--watch` flag it works perfect, but when the watcher is active, if I change a file which is not `./sass/import.scss`, for example`./sass/components/button.scss`, it seems the compiler tries to build it directly, without starting from `./sass/import.scss`.

Is that true?

Does exists some way to avoid this and tell the watcher to build `./sass/import.scss` every time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You told sass to watch only the import.scss file. 
See the [documentation](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#user-content-command-line-interface) for all the command line options you need and remember to let the included filenames to start with an "_" to prevent that they get compiled to a css single file as well.

`node-sass --recursive --watch ./sass/ --output source/css/`

Comment: The `--recursive` helped me a lot! Thanks :)